# My client can't see any of products - Magento

Tags: caching, magento, invisible

I am having a weird situation. I worked on a magneto ecommerce website. My friends and I can see the products on the website, but only my client can't see any of them.

I suspected magento cache, so I refreshed and disabled all the caches. My client still can't see all the products. I made him to clear browser cache. It didn't work as well. I also let him use FF or Safari. He still can't see the products.

What is the problem??? I can't try any other things now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to checking multiple websites, are you logged in or do you have a specific customer group? Magento allows you to show products only to certain customers. Check to make sure that as a logged-out, anonymous user, you can see the products.

Hope that helps,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured multiple stores, websites or store views in your Magento instance? Whether or not Magento displays a product depends on a lot of settings, but if one user can, and another user cannot see them, it's most likely related to which store view they are accessing.

The store view Magento is showing isn't always determined by the URL alone, there is also a setting which is stored in the cookie and can be changed via a dropdown (in the default templates anyway).

Stores are configured via System > Manage Stores. If you have multiple rows in there you have multiple store views (or websites or stores).